# Magic Line & jQuery origLeft undefined working on homepage not other pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, magicline

Using Magic Line on a site and it works perfectly on the homepage. Added another page and the magic line no longer works. The error that is show in the dev inspect is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined.

The site is a wordpress site with a Divi child theme.
The javascript file has been enqueued in the child theme `functions.php` file.

The Javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var $el, leftPos, newWidth, ratio, origLeft, origRatio,
    origWidth = 100,
    $mainNav  = $("#nav");

$mainNav.append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

origLeft  = $(".current_page_item a").position().left;
newWidth  = $(".current_page_item").width();
origRatio = newWidth / $magicLine.width();

$magicLine
    .css("transform", "translateX("+origLeft+"px) scaleX("+origRatio+")");

$("li").not("#magic-line").hover(function() {
    $el = $(this).find("> a");
    leftPos = $el.position().left;
    newWidth = $el.parent().width();
    ratio = newWidth / origWidth;
    $magicLine
        .css("transform", "translateX("+leftPos+"px) scaleX("+ratio+")");
}, function() {
    $magicLine
        .css("transform", "translateX("+origLeft+"px) scaleX("+origRatio+")");
});});
```

The html is:

```
<div id="navContainer">
<a href="#">
  <div id="logo" class="hvr-bounce-in">
    <img id="mamboLogo" src="mamboLogo.png">
      <div class="logoText">
        <h1 class="title">Mambo Media</h1>
        <p class="tagLine">Film and Animation</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</a>
<div class="nav-wrap">
  <ul class="group" id="nav">
    <li class="nav-item current_page_item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Work</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Team</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any help would be brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out after reading about another issue. the javascript is solid the problem was not paying attention to the html. class wasn't being specified for the active link correctly on the pages that weren't working. noob error.